# Vertical Chat scrolling is not working in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scroll

I am using chat scrolling in VUE JS. I want to have message scroll at the bottom of the page at every time when new message come or page load. I am trying to have a page scroll code in a function which works little bit surprisingly.

```
var container = this.$el.querySelector(".messages");
container.scrollTop = container.scrollHeight;
```

It is working but it cannot fully scroll down to the full bottom. With this, scroll remains at some position between top and bottom. When i trigger this one more time then it takes scroll to the full bottom. I want to have scroll on the bottom on first click not on two clicks. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your 'container' is full-filled on body or root element?
your code looks just fine...

You may better check:
1) URL bar height issue (on mobile)
2) HTML hierarchy and its css
3) CSS box model and default css values of html.

But still probs are following, If I were you,
I'll add a MAGIC PIXEL NUMBER (which bigger than the margin) like a boss!

Bigger (than its document height) value of scrollTop isn't throw any error. (but watch its cumulation..)